# How to configure nginx reverse proxy in Google Cloud Run to point to a different Google Cloud Run app

Tags: nginx, google-cloud-platform, nginx-reverse-proxy, google-cloud-run

I have a web application fronted by nginx set up in GCP Cloud Run, which works great. I am trying to use nginx to proxy requests to a certain route to *another GCP Cloud Run service*.  For example -- I want requests to `https://my-cloud-run-frontend.app.run` to resolve to `https://my-cloud-run-frontend.run.app`, however I want requests to  `https://my-cloud-run-frontend.run.run/api/*` to be proxied to `https://my-cloud-run-backend.run.app`.

Both cloud run services do use IAM Auth.

When I run my services in docker containers locally, the proxying works great.  Likewise, if I remove IAM auth from the `frontend` app in my Cloud Run settings, things seem to work.

However, with IAM auth enabled, requests to `https://my-cloud-run-frontend.run.app` succeed, but requests to `https://my-cloud-run-frontend.run.app/api/` fail as unauthorized (specifically, the error is thrown from the `frontend` cloud run app).

I've confirmed that the auth works by using the same auth token and making a request to `https://my-cloud-run-backend.run.app` as well as to `https://my-cloud-run-frontend.run.app` directly, and it works fine.

Doing some research, I saw that I may need to set a `Host` header, so I tried setting the header `Host` to my destination (the `https://my-cloud-run-backend.run.app` url). This had the effect of making calls to `https://my-cloud-run-frontend.run.app/api` return a 400 error.

My `nginx.conf.template` file:

```
server {

  access_log /dev/stdout;
  listen 8080;

  location / {

    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    proxy_set_header Authorization $http_authorization;
    proxy_pass_header Authorization;
    proxy_pass_request_headers on;

  }

  location /api/ {
    proxy_pass https://my-cloud-run-backend.run.app/;
    proxy_set_header Authorization $http_authorization;
    proxy_pass_header Authorization;
    proxy_set_header Host https://my-cloud-run-backend.run.app;
    proxy_pass_request_headers on;
    rewrite ^/api(.*)$ $1 break;
  }

  error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;

  location = /50x.html {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
  }

}
```

Comment: It won't work because the Authorization header is also changed by Google Front End (the identity token signature is removed to prevent any reusability). Why don't you use Load Balancer instead?

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand -- when does that happen?  I thought with the way I have nginx set up, it should be re-adding that header, no?  The load balancer is not on my list of approved technologies, and feels a bit heavy handed/expensive  for this purpose (proxying a front end to a back end and forwarding auth).

Comment: For security reason, the identity token provided in the Authorization Header is truncated: the signature part has been removed. You can use that token to know the identity of the requester, but you can't reuse the token for a subsequent query.

Comment: Understood, thank you.  I assume that's so it doesn't get logged/saved/stolen right?  I suppose I could pass in a token as a parameter, (like a `myservice.run.app?upstream-token=ey.....`) but I assume the security implications of that are less than ideal?

Answer (score 7):

You can achieve your use case without authentication on your backend. In fact, you can deploy the API Cloud Run unauthenticated but with [ingress set to internal only](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/securing/ingress)

Then, on your reverse proxy Cloud Run, you have to add a [Serverless VPC connector and set the egress to all](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/connecting-vpc)

That design accepts only authenticated and authorized request on the reverse proxy and makes the API backend only reachable by the reverse proxy (or other internal resource in your VPC).

---

This design will work but there is several tradeoff:

- You can't define who has access to your API backend. It's "internal": any internal resource in your project can access it. In addition, if you have access to the reverse proxy you also have access to the backend, not different level of authorization possible here (at least with Google Cloud services. You can add homemade authorization check in your code)
- The Serverless VPC connector cost is higher than a Load Balancer
- The design is complex for only a redirect

Comment: Thank you for that explanation, it's super helpful.  I may go down this route -- or try the load balancer if I can get it approved.  Do you have a recommendation of how to do this with a load balancer?  I am not as familiar with that particular offering.

Comment: With Load Balancer, the documentation is pretty good. You define serverless NEG backend with your Cloud Run services, then you map your route to the serverless NEG.

Comment: Would an Internal HTTP(S) load balancer be the recommended one to use in that case?

Comment: Internal LB are only accessible internally, by private IP. Not sure it is your use case.

Comment: Unfortunateu, If you have many cloud run services LB can't work as there is a limit on how many you can link. Imagine you need LB for dev/stage/prod/sandbox is actually too costly.